# How to get the IMEI in react-native

Tags: react-native

Can anyone tell me how to get the IMEI number of a device using react-native?

I tried [react-native-imei](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-imei), but it does not appear to be working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why do you need the IMEI?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using device/emulator with Android 10+ you must set necessary permissions.
See https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#non-resettable-device-ids.
If you want a sample code, just comment my answer.

Comment: the permissions are already given, still its not working