# Retrieving IMEI number in React Native

Tags: reactjs, imei

I am working on a React Native application and need to retrieve the IMEI number of the device for a specific use case.

Is there a recommended and secure way to obtain the IMEI number in React Native?react native device Info no support

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get IMEI number in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70377596/get-imei-number-in-react-native)

Comment: this also: [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75612095/how-to-get-the-imei-in-react-native)